# Maven Project getting some Heap Size Error, Maven or Java?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, heap-memory

when i run my programm and add a 10MB Excel and calculate something i get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:705)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:613)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:5593)
    at org.logicng.formulas.FormulaFactory.or(FormulaFactory.java:532)
    at org.logicng.formulas.FormulaFactory.naryOperator(FormulaFactory.java:372)
    at org.logicng.formulas.FormulaFactory.naryOperator(FormulaFactory.java:359)
    at org.logicng.formulas.NAryOperator.restrict(NAryOperator.java:130)
    at org.logicng.formulas.NAryOperator.restrict(NAryOperator.java:129)
    at org.logicng.formulas.NAryOperator.restrict(NAryOperator.java:129)
    at                                                                                                                                     
org.logicng.transformations.qe.ExistentialQuantifierElimination.apply(ExistentialQuantifierElimination.java:74)
    at ToPue.calculatePueForPos(ToPue.java:59)
    at PosvHandler.calculatePosv(PosvHandler.java:21)
    at PueChecker$EqualBtnClicked.actionPerformed(PueChecker.java:192)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
```

I searched everything and tested to set the maven memory higher.

[image: Intellij Log]

I set the heap space for java to 12gb
The maximum usage of the heapspace is 201MB. Why isn´t it using the whole memory?

Can somebody help

Comment: Java version? How do you run it? Have you tried to produce a dump, to debug the problem?

Comment: Did you try setting the heap in the VM Options field of the Run/Debug Configuration for the app that you are starting inside the IDE? IDE heap size settings have no effect on your app.

Comment: Hi, im using the jdk-14.0.1 and IntelliJ 2020.1. I set the Run Configurations with -ea -Xms1024M -Xmx8192M. As you can see on the screenshot above it will just use around 200MB of 12Gb Ram... and it runs in the heap space error

Comment: The heap size used by IDE has no relation to the heap size used by the app you start from the IDE. Post the command line you see in Run console.